# different view in my phone and android studio preview why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: Android studio preview]

[image: Nokia 2 preview]

[image: Display configuration]

Why is it showing different layout in my phone?

Comment: You have to show us the code behind that layout, otherwise there's no way to figure out what's going on

Comment: may be you are using tools attribute for preview, providing the xml code will help to find the reason.

Comment: share your layout code here. as per your images, looks like your preview display configuration is different then your phone display

Comment: do you used constraint layout ? If yes simply infer your constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes because of the density you use in android studio and the density of your phone doesn't match and sometimes if you use constraints layout and you don't declare the constraints when you run the app the widgets automatically jumps to top and sometimes because of wrong constraints and sometimes when the android studio IDE crushes. It has many reasons and without seeing your codes i can't say why is this.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

*It happens sometimes because there are many phones in market with different density. So density of emulator and your phone does not match, and it is also depend how you write the code. So please share your code.*